# The entity set is not defined in the entity container

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

[Cross posted on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28b8f24e-55be-4ac6-8000-c664715d5e48/the-entity-set-is-not-defined-in-the-entity-container?forum=csharpgeneral)

We use manual code first Entity Framework for System.Data.Sqlite

So when creating a new entity, we manually create the table, the c# object, and add the DbSet to our context.

I have a very simple object created and I am getting this error when trying to query the context. I have checked the column names and data types many times but I don't see a mismatch here. Also there are no foreign key relationships defined even though the fields have id in the name. Just a standalone table.

**The weirdest part is that I can add a new entity to the context, save changes, and it will be persisted to the db.** However in the next line when trying to retrieve the entities I get `The entity set is not defined in the entity container` error. I have also noticed that if I hover over an instantiated context, all the other db sets will have the EF SQL such as `SELECT EXTENT1.myCol as myCol`, but the `department_resources` set just says `{System.Data.Entity.DbSet<department_resource>}`.

Any ideas on what the issue is here?

Below are excerpts of my files:

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE department_resources (
dep_res_key VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, 
department_id INT NOT NULL, 
resource_id INT NOT NULL);
```

**department_resource.cs**

```
[Table("department_resources")]
public class department_resource 
{
    [Key]
    public string dep_res_key { get; set; }
    public int department_id { get; set; }
    public int resource_id { get; set; }
}
```

**MyContext.cs**

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
 public DbSet<department_resource> department_resources { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Usage**

```
using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
{
    db.department_resources.Add(new department_resource() 
      { dep_res_key = "anID", 
        resource_id = 22, 
        department_id = 23 }); // Works

    db.SaveChanges(); // Also works. Even persists to db

    var foo = from r in db.department_resources 
              select r.resource_id; // Doesn't work. Will error as soon as I try to use foo. Like assigning to a combo box item source. Or even just enumerating the results

    var bar = db.department_resources; // Also doesn't work.

}
```

Comment: Did u check in database ? Is this saved

Comment: Yes it is saved in db

Comment: Could you please try by initiating a new db context `using (MyContext db = new MyContext()) ` and try to fetch inside this new context

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you I am already doing this. If you look at the sample usage I have provided I am using this code to test. I actually added the save changes for additional testing but originally just tried to fetch inside using block

Comment: This must be a bug. If saving is successful you evidently didn't do anything terribly wrong. Can you query `department_resources` with a new context instance directly afterwards?

Comment: I'll give that a try when I get home although I don't see why that would be necessary. This table is already populated with data I was just adding a row with EF expecting possibly a different error to occur. Originally I was only querying from the new context.

Comment: I don't know if it's related to your problem (might well be) but I notice you're not defining your DbSet as virtual. I'd expect to see `public virtual DbSet<department_resource> department_resources { get; set; }`

Comment: @Gert Arnold I tried creating a new context after disposing the one that saves to query but the same error occurs. I am thinking this is a bug as well.

Comment: @Tone I changed it to a virtual DbSet but the issue remains. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with deferred execution. Although you're assigning `foo` and `bar` within your `using` block, they're not getting evaluated until they're actually used, after `MyContext` has been disposed.

You need to force them to evaluated within your using block. e.g. by converting the results to lists.

Also I notice you've declared them as `vars` within your `using` block. They'll need to be defined outside of it to be able to use them outside (perhaps you just did this in your sample to simplify?)

```
List<int> foo;
List<department_resource> bar;

using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
{
    db.department_resources.Add(new department_resource() 
      { dep_res_key = "anID", 
        resource_id = 22, 
        department_id = 23 }); // Works

    db.SaveChanges(); // Also works. Even persists to db

    foo = (from r in db.department_resources 
              select r.resource_id).ToList();

    bar = db.department_resources.ToList();

}
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397906.aspx)

> the query variable itself only stores the query commands. The actual
>   execution of the query is deferred until you iterate over the query
>   variable in a foreach statement. This concept is referred to as
>   deferred execution
>
> **Forcing Immediate Execution**
>
> Queries that perform aggregation functions over a range of source elements must first iterate over
>   those elements. Examples of such queries are Count, Max, Average, and
>   First. These execute without an explicit foreach statement because the
>   query itself must use foreach in order to return a result. Note also
>   that these types of queries return a single value, not an IEnumerable
>   collection.
>
> You can also force execution by putting the foreach loop immediately
>   after the query expression. However, by calling ToList or ToArray you
>   also cache all the data in a single collection object.

Comment: I was actually using `(from r in db.department_resources 
              select r.resource_id).ToList();` originally but removed ToList() in order to purposely defer execution and help troubleshoot. I was hoping to see a Select statement or something helpful but no select statement is available when hovering over foo. Just `{System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery<int>}`. Adding the `ToList()` back results in the error occurring on the same line as assignment to `foo`

Comment: Sorry I'm stumped then. I can't see anything else in your code that might cause it. I'd suggest updating your question to include the `virtual` keyword, adding an example in your sample code where you force evaluation (e.g. with `ToList()`) and maybe adding a screenshot of what you see when you hover over `db`. Maybe somebody else will see an issue. Perhaps try regenerating your database from your model and see if it throws up any errors (and check the tables, etc. it creates), and also double check to make sure the code in the question exactly matches yours.